# AJAX file upload with Erlang Cowboy

Tags: jquery, ajax, erlang, cowboy

I have a problem with AJAX file uploading to Erlang Cowboy. I can stream the file upload the with mutltpart/form-data

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But I cannot stream the file uploading using AJAX because it's not part of cow_multipart data as the uploaded files are stored along the cowboy_req:body_qs like as the following:

```
[{<<"-----------------------------9807164986589917941183868187\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name">>, <<"\"0\"\r\n\r\n[object HTMLInputElement]\r\n-----------------------------9807164986589917941183868187\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params\"\r\n\r\nkey=162">>}, {<<"profileID">>,<<"24">>}, {<<"testiing">>, <<"123\r\n-----------------------------9807164986589917941183868187--\r\n">>}], 19])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, by add contentType and processData = false